# Error: "warning: control reaches end of non-void function" using Eigen tensor?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor, return-type

I have two similar functions one uses Eigen tensor and the other doesn't. However, the first code returns the error:
Function1

```
double Arr1DMax(double arr[], int arrLength){
    double max = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
        if (arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
double Function1(Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3>& In ,double cfl, double kmax, double maxdt){
double *absArr;
absArr = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny *sizeof(double));
memset(absArr, 42, nx*ny* sizeof(double));

        double vMaxArr[10];  
        Eigen::Tensor<double, 0> AbsMaxAsTensor = In.abs().maximum();
        double max = Arr1DMax(vMaxArr, 10);
        
        double dt = cfl / (max * kmax);  

        if (dt < maxdt){
        return dt;
        }else {
            return maxdt;
        }
fftw_free(absArr);
} //ERROR here
```

Error message I get:

```
 warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 1360 | }
```

Function2 is the same but uses 2D arrays instead:

```
double max2D(double arr2D[]){
    double maxVal = 0.;
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++){
            if (arr2D[j + ny*i] > maxVal){
                maxVal = arr2D[j + ny*i];
            }
        }
    }   
    return maxVal;
}

double Function2( double In[] ,double cfl, double kmax, double maxdt){
double *absArr;
absArr = (double*) fftw_malloc(nx*ny *sizeof(double));
memset(absArr, 42, nx*ny* sizeof(double));

        double vMaxArr[10];
        vMaxArr[0] = max2D(vexbx); 
        double max = Arr1DMax(vMaxArr, 10);
        
        double dt = cfl / (max * kmax);  

        if (dt < maxdt){
        return dt;
        }else {
            return maxdt;
        }
fftw_free(absArr);
} //NO ERROR
```

I see how by adding `return 0;` at the end of Function1 I can get rid of the error, but I am trying to understand why Fnction2 above returns no error even though I have no `return 0;` statement at the end??

Comment: You may be confusing the compiler by putting `fftw_free(absArr);` after the `return`. That line is unreachable, but the compiler might be assuming that it is somehow reachable, otherwise you wouldn't have put it there. It is a good thing that the compiler is warning you (even if the message is not correct) that there is a problem there. What do you expect it to do there?

Answer (score 1):

If you use good coding standards, you will see that F2 returns in ALL control paths.  It's basically

```
dostuff();
if (a)
  return 1;
else
  return 0;
fftvw_free();
```

Comment: hmm... so does F1.  Not sure. why F1 is warning.